# Select & Preview Thumbnail View

Tags: usability

I have list of thumbnails on 5 different categories, wanted to select according to categories, view the thumbnail and get back to the category.

The list I have as a hierarchical grid view with 2 level sub-category.

Do i really need a search bar for this ?
Do i need to show all the thumbnail first and then categories using select drop-down?
Are there any design patterns to reference?

Answer (score 1):

1. A search bar is always better, but if implemented it should be able to show search results grouped under each category like

> **Category 1**
>
> 1. item one
> 2. item two
>
> **Category 2**
>
> 1. item one
> 2. item two

2. How many items might be under each category? If they are less than, say 30, you could show them all under one list with section header as Category name.
3. If there are many, a drop down is help full. Depending on use case each Category might also be used as a filter.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of handling this. Places I would look for inspiration are iTunes shop, Amazon homepage, Google Play and eBay homepage. These places all have to deal with the issue you are asking about: Thumbnails within categories.

Comment: Can you summarise the potential solutions?